# Grails UnexpectedRollbackException in Controller

Tags: spring, grails, transactions, spring-transactions

My Grails Service calls a plugin which throws a runtime exception.  In my case, I don't care about the exception, so it is swallowed.

```
MyGrailsService {
    def myMethod {
         ...
         try {
             //callPlugin
         } catch (Exception ex) {
              ...
         }
    }
}
```

All fine, exception is caught and processing continues. However, in my Controller, I have a `catch (Throwable t)` block, which I am not expecting to get executed because the exception is swallowed.  It turns out the `catch (Throwable t)` block is executed because Grails throws a   a `org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException`
which of course I do not want it to do.  I guess I am getting this because the exception the plugin throws is runtime, so Grails rolls back the Transaction.

I don't want this `UnexpectedRollbackException` being thrown.

Any tips?

Comment: I encountered a similar situation and was similarly puzzled about it. In my case, it was a clean and pragmatic solution to avoid the exception from being thrown in the first place by checking the data before calling the function. But obviously there are a lot of scenarios in which that isn't possible or desirable.

Answer (score 0):

What i would have done is

```
class MyService{

  static transactional = false

  def myMethod {
         ...
         try {
             //callPlugin
         } catch (Exception ex) {
              ...
         }
    }

  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  def someMethod {
    // Some code here  
  }


}
```

The above code will make all the methods in the service non transactional and we will explicitly make the methods transactional which we want.

However once more thing can be a point to be taken care of, the method of the plugin you are calling, that method can itself be a transactional method, which on error may get rolled back and throw a UnexpectedRollbackException. So you have to check it once if the plugin method is transactional.